# allow 0 at first digit when using JavaScript replace and match method

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to force user key in the value with the format that I wish, 
I make the input can only insert number and it will auto add `-` at the 7th value.

But I found that if the user want to key in `000319-19-2939` the result will become `319192-93-9`.
This javascript will delete the `0` when it come with the first.

```js
document.getElementById('others_textb').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,6})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] :  + x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
      });
```

```html
<input id="others_textb" type="text" name="number" placeholder="xxxxxx-xx-xxxx" >
```

What I want is to make `0` can be the first number in this input.

Comment: Test if zero is the first character, if so, append zero to your output. Why bang your head? ;)

Comment: Thankyou for the logic, but this seem can be solve by the answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The you are coercing the first matched group to an integer through `+x[1]`:

```
e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] :  + x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
                                 ^
```

You can remove the coercion (`+`), and the rest of the code should preserve the leading zeros.

```js
document.getElementById('others_textb').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,6})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = 
    !x[2] 
      ? x[1] 
      : x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] 
                              ? '-' + x[3] 
                              : '');
});
```

```html
<input id="others_textb" type="text" name="number" placeholder="xxxxxx-xx-xxxx">
```